# Should rep requirements for tag creation be higher?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tagging, privileges

There are, IMO, quite a lot of badly tagged questions and... not very good tags. Some of them were discussed on meta recently; some of these discussions show, IMO, that users who created these tags don't always understand tagging system of Math.SE well enough.

On Meta.SO one needs 500 rep to create a new tag, on SO — 1500 (!) rep. On Math.SE — just 300 rep.

Since its creation Math.SE has grown a lot. Maybe now it's time to (ask to) raise reputation requirements for creating new tag on Math.SE? (Say, to 1000 rep?)

(Idea suggested by [Tito Piezas III](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/4781/tito-piezas-iii) in [this comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12314/do-we-really-need-a-ramanujan-radicals-tag#comment48374_12314).)

Comment: Somewhat related feature request: [Warning for new tags](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/11140/)

Comment: I didn't even realise the value was variable among different SE sites. I agree this would be a good idea, seeing as it seems to not be hard to change.

Comment: Great feature. I still think that the warning for new tags is a great idea, but this seems like a first step in reducing tag noise.

Comment: I would put it even higher. A low limit was ok in the early days of the site, but it is time to raise the bar now. Ideally I might want to require experience on Meta, because exposure to relevant discussion is only available here.

Comment: Is there a case to be made for a canonical tag destruction thread, similar to the one for reopen votes?  I ask because "probabilty" got created a few days ago, I posted about it in the Tagging chat, and so far it seems to have escaped moderator attention.

Comment: @hardmath Maybe [Tag merging and synonyms](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1363/) should be used for this purpose

Comment: @hardmath For cases like "probabilty", just retagging the question(s) with the typo'ed tag should be enough. If a tag is unused, it is automatically deleted after - iirc - 24 hours. Of course if a typo surfaces again and again, sterner measures must be taken.

Comment: @hardmath Sorry, I've misread your question — that thread is for discussion of changes, for obvious typos just retag the question

Comment: Erm... what now? Do we need to do to something to get the attention of the powers that be?

Comment: Allegedly they monitor the feature request tags through meta sites. There is a chance that this will take effect soon.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After a quick check on this, we've increased the threshold to the suggested 1000 reputation. That seems a saner number than 1500 for here. Only a handful of tags are created in the 1000-1500 reputation range, many of which were things like [conditional-probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditional-probability) and [partial-derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partial-derivative) that are quite frequently used.

Comment: Wooooooooooooooooo! (And I'm speaking for at least several users, I'm sure!)

Answer (score 18):

I agree; there is much less need for  new tags on an established math Q&A site than on a technology-oriented Q&A  site. On a tech  Q&A,  users are likely to bring up questions about a new  gadget  or a new version of some  software that was just released. Here we don't normally get questions about mathematical areas that were just recently invented.  Unless we count [kalle numbers](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1411/). Or [caluclus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caluclus), which was invented just an hour ago.

I   suggest setting the limit at 1500 as on SO, simply because it seems SE prefers to [avoid too many  special cases](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4770/) among the sites.  But either 1000 or 1500 would be an improvement.

Comment: Perhaps we are in need of a [tag:kalle-numbers] tag for such innovations.

Comment: -1 for bringing up that infernal thread; +2 for the rest of the content.

Comment: Retagging someones questions as [tag:kalle-numbers] would certainly make for a powerful insult.